# Mysql Group By incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7

The sql query:

select *, sum(field1) as sumfield1 from knowntable where match(producer) 
against('+xyz*' in boolean mode) group by producer having sumfield1>0 
order by sumfield1 desc limit 10;

throws the following exception when running with local tomcat:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

The above query is working perfectly in the production system/tomcat. Both servers (local and prod) are accessing the same database.

I have already tried the following solutions:

```
1) SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

2) Add the following lines in the /etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf file:
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I have checked all the answers on this website with related exception but no solution is working for me

Please help

Comment: What is `select ,`?  Can you post your exact query?  But the error is self-explanatory.  Any field in your `select` list not included in an aggregate function (i.e. `sum`) need to be included in the `group by` clause...

Comment: A simple way to solve non aggregated columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171